# Inquiry of Bot Framework "ChannelAccount object"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, mention

Following this document:
Bot Framework REST API > API reference > Get conversation members
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#get-conversation-members

We have noticed that the ChannelAccount object for some members, who have never sent a message, cannot be obtained from the "Get conversation members" API.

Is this the product design originally?

If so, could you advise how to mention with never interact users? By MS Graph API?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatmessagemention?view=graph-rest-1.0

Or any advise to send mention message if we only know AADObject of users in teams?

Thank you in advance.